# In C#, Do Properties of a Class Get Initialized Concurrently Or Sequentially?

Tags: c#

Suppose I'm composing an object whose properties need to be converted from other values determined in a method, such as:

```
var var1;
var var2;

//do stuff with var1 and var2

MyClass myClass = new MyClass
{
    Property1 = var1,
    Property2 = var2
};
```

If the properties of `MyClass` are both evaluated and set at the same time (where this is possible), I think it may be more efficient to devolve the operations that set `var1` and `var2` to separate methods, like this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass
{
    Property1 = SetProperty1(),
    Property2 = SetProperty2()
}

private static object SetProperty1()
{
    //do stuff
}

private static object SetProperty2()
{
    //do stuff
}
```

If, however, each property is evaluated in order (as one sees when stepping through code like this), any such benefit from breaking out new methods is lost.

Do properties of a `new`ed object get initialized concurrently, or in order?

Comment: They're initialized in the order you specify the assignments.

Comment: Computers aren't good at doing things concurrently, unless you expect your objects to be set up by multiple threads.

Comment: @Enigmativity Computers are *very* good at doing things concurrently.  Even with a single thread, it's likely spending very little of its time only doing a single operation at once.  What it *does* do is work hard to ensure that the behavior of running various operations concurrently cannot be observably distinguished from what *would* happen if it ran entirely sequentially, allowing programmers to write code *as if* the programs run everything sequentially, because writing concurrent code is very hard *for programmers* (to do right), even though it's super easy *for computers*.

Comment: @Servy - Do you mean CPU pipelining?

Comment: @Enigmativity Among other similar techniques, yes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is important to understand what happens here.

This statement:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass
{
    Property1 = var1,
    Property2 = var2
};
```

Actually compiles down to this:

```
MyClass temp = new MyClass();
temp.Property1 = var1;
temp.Property2 = var2;
MyClass myClass = temp;
```

The reason for this temp variable is that if you're instead of assigning to a local variable assign it to a property, that property won't contain a halfway-initialized object. It will only receive the object instance once initialization is complete.

So to answer your question, object initializers will assign the property values sequentially, and also in the order you wrote them, not in the order the corresponding properties are defined in the type, if this differ. This is because it might be important to order the side-effects assigning to properties *might* have, though I would advice against creating objects with such side-effects as they can be quite brittle.

**However**, any code inspecting the `myClass` variable (or field, or property) will either see the old value (likely `null`), or the completely (according to your assignments) assigned object.

---

As an example of what would happen if you didn't use this temp variable:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
// what if some other code can access myClass here, because you're really
// assigning to a property or to a field?
myClass.Property1 = var1;
// then this assignment above wouldn't be done yet
...
```

Comment: This was a very thorough and helpful response! Tusen takk!

Answer (score 2):

They are set sequentially.

See http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/csharp-3.0/object-initializers/ for some examples of what it does 'under the hood'.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the others said: the properties are initialized in the order you specify the assignments.

You can try this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private object _property1;
    private object _property2;

    public object Property1 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _property1; 
        }

        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Property1 set");
            _property1 = value;
        }
    }

    public object Property2 
    {
        get
        {
            return _property2;
        }

        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Property2 set");
            _property2 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is approximately what is generated, when you use the `public object Property { get; 
set; }` syntax. Except for the `Console.WriteLine`

When you use this class like this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass
{
     Property2 = 1,
     Property1 = "a"
};
```

The output will be:

```
Property2 set
Property1 set
```